# Material3 theme in jetpack compose gives different color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I just created a new project in jetpack compose with material 3. I did not change anything in the project.

Just in Theme.kt file i added background

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Color.Red,
    secondary = Color.White,
    background = Color(0xFF5CB15A)
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Color.Red,
    secondary = Color.Black,
    background = Color(0xFF5CB15A)

)
```

Now when i use it in my composable file

```
TextButton(modifier = Modifier
                            .background(
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                            ).....
```

I get completely different color. Why is that?

```
MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()


            PetCareComposeTheme {
                GetStarted()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you check the color? In the emulator/physique device or in the compose Preview with @Preview annotation?

Comment: In real device...

Comment: Can you add the code of your main activity specifically the setContent{}

Comment: At first i thought you didn't use the app_nameTheme{} function in your main activity but it seems that you are using it so I don't see any problem why it shouldn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Material 3, dynamic color is enabled by default. Try disabling it.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PetCareTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = false, // change to false to disable by default
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Dynamic color overview : https://m3.material.io/styles/color/dynamic-color/overview